# How to refresh the data in a jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have been trying to get a grid to be updated from the datasource when a button is pushed.

So I have in the click event something like this:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('trigger','reloadGrid');
```

However this does not work and I get an error thrown for unknown method 'trigger'

I have also tried

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('trigger("reloadGrid")');
```

How would I execute this function?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
$('#grid').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );
```

Comment: I do wish they would change the documentation for jqGrid as right now it is a bit deceiving..

Comment: The `bind()` and `trigger()` methods are part of the jQuery core, FYI

Comment: yes they are but their documentation does not make that obvious and the reloadGrid function is not listed in green as somethin requiring a "special method of calling"

Comment: Is this method of refreshing memory-leak-safe ?

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me.

```
jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('clearGridData');
jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: dataToLoad});
jQuery('#grid').trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: Where did you put this code? Could you be more specific please, I'm newbie on it. Tks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to reload jqGrid with new data

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newdata= //You call Ajax peticion//

$("#idGrid").clearGridData();

$("#idGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {data:newdata)});
$("#idGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

in event update data table